# Can you use string formatting for classes in Python?

Tags: python, string, class, format

I need to name classes certain things, for example:

```
for a in range(10):
    class Class#"%s"(object): % (num)
         '''Class Content'''
    num += 1
```

My question, is this possible, and if not, what is an alternative.

Comment: The fact that you find yourself needing to do this suggests that your approach could be improved. What is the bigger picture; why are you doing this, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow - there's no need to add solved to your question. By clicking the checkmark you've already indicated to the wider community that you've got the answer you need. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben, sorry, I'm just used to that from using the Ubuntu forums, my bad. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using metaclasses (stuff that is used to create classes). Example:

```
>>> type('ClassName', (), {})
<class '__main__.ClassName'>
```

Second argument is a tuple of base classes, third argument is a dictionary containing `attribute name` -> `attribute value` pairs:

```
>>> cls = type('ClassName', (object,), {'varname': 'var'})
>>> cls.varname
'var'
```

From the [documentation on `type` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type):

With three arguments, return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the class statement. The name string is the class name and becomes the `__name__` attribute; the bases tuple itemizes the base classes and becomes the `__bases__` attribute; and the dict dictionary is the namespace containing definitions for class body and becomes the
`__dict__` attribute.

**Also** read [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/2301450) for more details.

Comment: So, from what I've read, I need to put the name, type(such as object), and the different attributes in a dictionary like this: {"self.var: var}.